# Persistence in Scalatra

Tags: scala, slick, scalatra

I am writing a web app with a angularJS front-end and Scalatra back-end. I have followed this tutorial on adding persistence using Slick and H2: http://www.scalatra.org/2.4/guides/persistence/slick.html

I want to know how to have the data in the database persist even if I restart the servlet.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If the data is in the database, restarting the servlet won't affect it. Please explain further

Comment: Don't worry, I was creating an in memory instance of the H2 database which doesn't persist data only provides a connection to the databse.